# How to use setTimeout synchronously in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, settimeout

Is it possible to get mentioned below output using `setTimout`. If yes, then please share your thought:-

```
console.log("1st");
setTimeout(()=>{
   console.log("2nd");
},0);
console.log("3rd");
```

**Output should be **

```
1st
2nd
3rd
```

Comment: No. That is not possible. If you want to execute some code *after* the timeout elapsed, you have to execute it in the callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Majed Badawi's answer shows a way to kind of achieve what you want, but it is just a construct that would be similar to simply put your 3rd log inside the setTimeout callback after the 2nd.

There are important conceptual reasons for this.

JavaScript is an event driven language, where you have something called an event loop that is checking for new events and process them non stop.

What you are looking for here, is a way to use `setTimeout` as you would you would use `sleep` in PHP, C or others. It simply doesn't exist.

`sleep` is a blocking instruction: the program waits for X seconds before proceeding. If you do this in JavaScript, you will prevent the event loop from running and you don't want to even try to do this. If you really insist, you can check if enough time has elapsed in a `while` statement, this will freeze your browser in a front end environment or prevent the handling of new requests in a back end environment.

More on this here https://cloudoki.com/js-dont-block-the-event-loop/

In contrast, `setTimeout` will fire an event to the provided listener after some time, the rest of the program (and the event loop) will continue to run.

Comment: Nice conceptual answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using async/await:

```js
const foo = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => { 
    console.log("2nd");
    resolve();
  }, 0);
});

(async () => {
  console.log("1st");
  await foo();
  console.log("3rd");
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` doesn't exist but you can just make it on your own

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

async function main() {
  console.log(1)
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log(2)
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log(3)
  await sleep(1000)
  return "done"
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

Thinking `async..await` are too magical? Let's try a generator -

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return Task(k => setTimeout(k, ms))
}

function* main() {
  console.log(1)
  yield sleep(1000)
  console.log(2)
  yield sleep(1000)
  console.log(3)
  yield sleep(1000)
  return Task(k => k("done"))
}

function Task(runTask) {
  return {
    runTask,
    bind: f => Task(k => runTask(x => f(x).runTask(k)))
  }
}

function coroutine(f) {
  function then(v) {
    let {done, value} = f.next(v)
    return done ? value : value.bind(then)
  }
  return then()
}

coroutine(main()).runTask(console.log)
```

Generators too sophisticated? Let's try a low-level abstraction -

```js
function sleep(ms, then) {
  setTimeout(then, ms)
}

function main(then) {
  console.log(1)
  sleep(1000, _ => {
    console.log(2)
    sleep(1000, _ => {
      console.log(3)
      sleep(1000, _ => {
        then("done")
      })
    })
  })
}

main(console.log)
```